# Screen losing saturation on acer Aspire 5742Z

Tags: graphics-card, display, acer-aspire

I bought an acer Aspire 5742Z laptop (with a Intel HD 128 MB GFX card) back in May 2011 and I think I'm starting to see a problem with the screen. I first noticed it last night and again this morning. Intermittently the screen seems to lose saturation, that is the picture seems greyer/more washed out than normal. It comes and goes lasting for only ten or so seconds at a time.

Is anyone aware of any issues with the model laptop or the graphics card that might cause this?

**Update**
I've just checked the Windows Update history and a new driver was installed on the 14/12/2011. I've rolled this driver back to see if that has any effect.

Comment: Maybe something with the display?

Comment: Dumb, but obvious question: are you perhaps accidentally hitting `Fn + Left/Right`?

Comment: Also, is this only when using battery or also when connected to the AC adapter? If your battery charge falls too low, it will switch to a power-saving mode using lower contrast. The thing is that if you are using something that uses a lot of CPU, it could estimate less than 10 mins. of remaining power and switch to low-brightness, but then when you stop doing that task, the estimated remaining time can go up and it then switches to the normal screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to the Intel Driver. Rolling back and blocking that update fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with your power saving modes, I have mine set only to do it when the laptop isn't plugged in to help preserve the battery longer.

Comment: It's losing saturation, not brightness.